# WSO2IS: Log4j 1.2 security vulnerability

Tags: log4j, wso2-identity-server

WSO2IS 5.8 include Log4j 1.2.17

A security vulnerability, CVE-2019-17571 has been identified against Log4j 1. Log4j includes a SocketServer that accepts serialized log events and deserializes them without verifying whether the objects are allowed or not. This can provide an attack vector that can be expoited.

Someone knows if this vulnerability can be exploited in the context of WSO2IS 5.8?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

WSO2 is very frequently issuing security patches as and when the issues are discovered. Can you please write to security@wso2.com and check.

Also - as a security best practice we recommend to use security@wso2.com all the time to report security issues - this is a common practice followed by all open source projects.

**UPDATE**: Even though the WSO2 Identity Server 5.8.0 has this dependency, it does not use any of the functionalities provided by SocketServer. **So, anyone using 5.8.0 version is NOT affected.** Also, since IS 5.9.0 this dependency is upgraded to Log4j 2.

More details here: https://wso2.com/security

Comment: Prabath, where did you find the "update" information ? Would it be possible to provide me a link ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Felipe you can find the information here https://docs.wso2.com/display/Security/CVE-2019-17571

Comment: Thanks a lot Janak! It was exactly what I was looking for!